# Migrate WCF bindings from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core Full Framework

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to migrate an existent ASP.NET project to a ASP.NET Core Full Framework project. This project references a class library with .NET Framework 4.7.1.

The class library contains references to some WCF services.
The problem is that the old ASP.NET project has some bindings for WCF services defined in Web.config.

How can I set those binding in the ASP.NET Core project taking into consideration that Core uses appsettings.json files instead of Web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to move them to app.config. ASP.NET Core applications that run on .NET Framework are console applictions.